# god-mode: swap keys

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I'm using the Dvorak keyboard layout and have swapped `C-x` and `C-t`, because I find it easier to type on Dvorak.

```
(define-key key-translation-map [?\C-x] [?\C-t])
(define-key key-translation-map [?\C-t] [?\C-x])
```

I'm also using `god-mode`, though, so I'd like `x` to be swapped with `t` when in `god-local-mode`, such that typing `x` results in `C-t` and typing `t` results in `C-x`.  I have a very crude solution using `keyboard-translate`:

```
(defun my-god-swap-on ()
  (interactive)
  (keyboard-translate ?x ?t)
  (keyboard-translate ?t ?x))

(defun my-god-swap-off ()
  (interactive)
  (aset keyboard-translate-table ?t nil)
  (aset keyboard-translate-table ?x nil))

(add-hook 'god-mode-enabled-hook 'my-god-swap-on)
(add-hook 'god-mode-disabled-hook 'my-god-swap-off)
```

Although this works it is extremely inelegant as it modifies global state.  If I switched to a buffer where god-mode is not enabled, the translation would still be active.  I could add yet another hook for buffer switching to make sure that the translation is disabled when `god-local-mode` is inactive in the current buffer, but this seems like a very ugly mitigation technique.

Is it possible to restrict the effects to a keyboard translation to only a single minor mode?

If this is not possible, is there another more elegant way I could swap keys in `god-mode`?  I see that `god-mode` rewires all keys bound to `self-insert-command` to `god-mode-self-insert`, but this uses `this-command-keys-vector` to determine with what key it was called and I cannot seem to shadow the definition of `this-command-keys-vector` with a let binding to swap `x` and `t` in a wrapper before passing control to `god-mode-self-insert`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FWIW, here's your solution in 'before' advice form:

n.b. this is untested (I don't use god-mode).

```
(defadvice god-mode-lookup-key-sequence (before my-swap-x-t)
  "Swap ?x and ?t KEY arguments."
  (case (ad-get-arg 0)
    (?x (ad-set-arg 0 ?t))
    (?t (ad-set-arg 0 ?x))))
(ad-activate 'god-mode-lookup-key-sequence)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I knew there had to be a way to achieve this by advising the function, but I didn't know exactly how to do it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The general solution is to modify god-mode so that it takes the key translation mechanism into account. This way, it will work with any key translation you've set or will set (`C-h` causing `DEL` is another common one).

I had the same problem so I [filed a bug](https://github.com/chrisdone/god-mode/issues/75) and [wrote a patch](https://github.com/bard/god-mode/commit/4e84359e3e8e892ad341d1d40047bd12b5dee284) that fixes it, at least for `C-` combinations. It changes the last sexp of `key-string-after-consuming-key` from:

```
(if key-string-so-far
    (concat key-string-so-far " " next-modifier next-key)
  (concat next-modifier next-key))
```

To:

```
(let* ((next-literal-key-string (concat next-modifier next-key))
       (translation (lookup-key key-translation-map
                                (read-kbd-macro next-literal-key-string t)))
       (next-interpreted-key-string
        (if translation
            (format-kbd-macro translation)
          next-literal-key-string)))

  (if key-string-so-far
      (concat key-string-so-far " " next-interpreted-key-string)
    next-interpreted-key-string))
```

Answer (score 1):

I now use this:

```
(defun original-god-mode-lookup-key-sequence (&optional key key-string-so-far) ())
(fset 'original-god-mode-lookup-key-sequence (symbol-function 'god-mode-lookup-key-sequence))

(defun god-mode-lookup-key-sequence (&optional key key-string-so-far)
  "Wrap original-god-mode-lookup-key-sequence.  Swap x and t."
  (interactive)
  (case key
    (?x (original-god-mode-lookup-key-sequence ?t key-string-so-far))
    (?t (original-god-mode-lookup-key-sequence ?x key-string-so-far))
    (t (original-god-mode-lookup-key-sequence key key-string-so-far))))
```

It makes a copy of `god-mode-lookup-key-sequence` as `original-god-mode-lookup-key-sequence` and then overrides it with a wrapper that performs the swap for `x` and `t`.  It's not elegant, but at least it won't leak.

Comment: Maybe `(defalias 'bar (symbol-function 'foo))` would be a simpler start?

Comment: It seems like a use-case for some 'before' advice, though. It could just change the argument if necessary, before the original function executes.